# Django REST framework throttling class or a middleware

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I've been studying how to use the Django REST framework with API key addon for a use-case:

I need to create logs of each API key that sends a request to each endpoint and base on type of account how many request is able to do it by each day.

I've been between using a throlling class but that seems to work for every API key but not depending on the type. Or create middleware that controls with table on the DB how many requests a type of API key is allowed to use.

Which of these approchs is better in this use-case or different a approch?

Comment: When it's something regarding directing requests, Middleware is always the way to go.

Comment: Thank you I gonna go for middleware then